# Comma sign is not typeable anymore

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard

I can't type comma sign today though I could do it yesterday.
It just doesn't appear in any gui app or terminal.
I can catch it with xev - it appears not to be hardware problem:

[image: screenshot of xev]

Not sure if it's related but I started to use a new external usb keyboard about a week ago. Current problem is persisted for both this usb keyboard and native laptop one

I would appreciate if someone point the direction to ellaborate

Upd: I could normally type comma in console mode. + If i switch layout the key with same keycode is also not typeable (specifically 'б' in cyrillic layout)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it.

Few days ago I've created custom shortcut for another keycode and it worked as supposed, but after restart it reapplied for wrong key for some reason. Deleting the shortcut resolves the problem.